# Pylint rule is unknown to sonar

Tags: python, eclipse, sonarqube, pylint

I am trying to use sonarQube with eclipse and python. 
The quality profile was sonar way, and it had only 11 rules to start with. So i added the pylint rules and they are marked as activated. But when i run analyze on the project I don't get any more issues compared to before (when i used 11 rules). Then console looks something like this:

```
16:38:49.091 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintSensor@1603ae07...
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
16:38:50.079 WARN  - Pylint rule 'C' is unknown in Sonar
```

Comment: So pylint seem to be run, since when i try to run sonar-runner I get the pylint printout, but the above messages when sonar is trying to parse the results. Is there something I have to configure in order for sonar to recognize the pylint rules? Except isntalling the python plugin and activate the rules.

Comment: Any advance regarding this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this kind of warnings for every Pylint rule that is disabled in the current quality profile, so it seems that this is a feature, not a bug (SonarQube 5.1.1 + Python plugin 1.6-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Based on https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-291 this behavior was improved starting with version 1.12